# How to capture packets drop at kernel and wi-fi driver?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I am sending a large number of packets from device 1 to device 2. But device 2 is not able to receive all the packets. I want to see if packets are dropped at the kernel and at wi-fi driver. Does anyone know how to measure that? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `ip -s link` or look at `/sys/class/net/*/statistics/` for the information reported by the LAN or WLAN driver to the kernel.

Try `iptables -vL` to see packets dropped by filtering rules.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much.